Is it possible to track the various links that initiate pageviews (and associate the 2) in Google Analytics (G4A) without GTM?
Suppose i have a signup page on my website. To get there, user's can either click the 'Signup Now' CTA that's present in the header of every page OR they can click any of the numerous 'signup' text links within the pages' text OR they can click the 'Signup Now' link in the footer that appears on every page.
I know that I can track these clicks fairly easily and tell exactly which link/button on which page was clicked. And I have also created an Exploration that allows me to view the referring page on my website for any given page. But is there a way to add a column or 2 to that Exploration (or create a report or whatever allows for it) that, say, lists the referring page's path as well as the element ID (or perhaps CSS selector of some sort) that was clicked on the referring page? Something that would look like this:

The only thing I can think of is to capture the click and send the referral data through the query string... and then loc it as some custom dimension? on the resulting page. So as a very basic example:
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const $el = e.target;
  if(!$el.matches('.some__specialized--classname')) return;   
  e.preventDefault();
  const curHref = $el.getAttribute('href');
  location.href = `${curHref}?refPath=${location.href}&el=${$el.id}`;   
})

And that seems REALLY hack-y and full of potential pitfalls. Maybe something with storing the  referral data in a cookie (or web storage) and matching session IDs? i'm hoping there's a more manageable, Google Analytics-y way of doing this.
EDIT:
Just in case it IS possible, my ultimate goal would be to be able to trace successful form submissions back to the element they clicked on which page to get to the signup page.

ok, a user navigates from page A to page B, on page B they click one of the "sign up now" CTAs. Now look at the collect request in the network tab. It will have page A's url as a referrer, and page B as the document, plus whatever you're tracking during the click in your eps.
So to me it looks like all you need is within the same hit. If you just want to associate sign up now clicks with the url where they happened, that's not a problem. You pull whatever dimension you store the clicks in and then the page dimension and you get the info. If you want to throw away the fact of the click from the picture and just see which pages people get from to your sign up page, you can do that too by filtering the page dimension to only select hits related to your signup page, and then pull the referrer dimension to see all the previous pages.
What you have there with the click callback is indeed awkward. I would go with GTM at this point for sure, which is also the best practice for a reason. Or two.
Anyway, consider also trying the path or funnel explorations. The path exploration seems to be satisfactory to what you're looking for.
Also, keep in mind that GA4's interface is somewhat new and the quality of development they pour into the interface is not exactly exhilarating. In other words, it can be buggy. I usually use BQ whenever I really need to look into the GA4/Firebase data, only using the interface for adhoc data debugging. BQ data, however, is a bit annoying too since they decided to needlessly nest eps and some other dimensions, so now one has to unnest them, but unnesting, in case of eps (where you need internal selects), can't be filtered or grouped by unless you either flatten the data or use CTEs, but CTEs are not as simple to use.

unfortunately much of that went over my head. But maybe I didn't explain it properly. The user starts on my Home page (PAGE A). From there, he clicks the 'Signup Now' CTA in the header bringing him to the Signup page (PAGE B). I know that on PAGE A, I can register the click and store the ID of the clicked element and even the destination page (PAGE B) but what I really need is some way to view all of that in association with PAGE B's pageview. I know i can get the referrer on PAGE B from the req but what about the clicked element on PAGE A? Something like: https://i.sstatic.net/LhhtXaAd.png

so you want to attribute not only the page that resulted in a conversion, but also the specific CTA... Uh. Well, generally this is not considered valuable information. The industry analyzes these things separately. First, which pages contribute how to the CTA clicks and which clicks are clicked more. Then, the signup page performance regardless of which of the internal CTAs led the person here. Because that usually doesn't matter. You're talking about attributing the specific clicks to the conversions. We don't do that with internal clicks, we do that with external campaigns.

But yes, if I needed to do an analysis like that, to answer the question of which signup CTA leads to more signups, I'd have to do that awkward thing of taking one session-level dimension and store the CTA clicked details in it and then pull its value on the success hit. But I would push back hard before doing this stuff. It's useless.

yeah i'm kind of also trying to assess the need for ALL the ways to get to the signup page. Maybe the data shows that when users get there by clicking the giant CTA in the header, they barely ever covert whereas when they get there from a text link on PAGE X, they almost always do (because they've read what it's all about rather than just clicking a button because it's big and in their face... idk). With that data, I might decide to use the real estate taken up by the giant 'Signup Now' CTA in the header for a different CTA or other more useful content. Sounds like it's pretty involved tho.

Theoretically, it seems feasible. In practice, people who click the giant CTA will convert just the same as those clicking the text CTAs. Even if you see that there's a difference, what are you gonna do? Get rid of the big CTA? That will lead to a drop of conversions for sure. You never want to get useless insights. Only actionable stuff should be looked at. Vanity insights only feel good.

Even if you see that there's a difference, what are you gonna do? Get rid of the big CTA?

Even if you see that there's a difference, what are you gonna do? Get rid of the big CTA? Maybe. That's valuable real estate. Maybe it's better to display the phone number or store hours there... or some other useful content. My point is that it could be actionable.

No, you're trying to rationalize the effort of tracking it. In the real life, if you were a PO asking me to track it, I would refuse. Well a PO would know for sure they would never get rid of that big juicy button in the top right. But hey, if you still want the tracking - you can have it. You'll have to either export the data as is and analyze it in SQL, or spend a session-level custom dimension, which would be easier.

The big juicy CTA is all part of the hypothetical picture I painted to try to simplify things. I get what you're saying and understand about using a session-level dimension to achieve something along the lines of what I laid out as well. Thanks for the input, for real - very informative.
